# Color transition of a link does not work in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have a link of an email on my page that is supposed to transition from its base color (light-ish green) to a darker green when you hover over it. I have confirmed that it works in Chrome, IE, Edge, and Opera. It only does not work in Firefox. I also have it where it does the same thing with a border at the bottom of the link when you hover over it and that works in Firefox fine, just not the color of the link for some reason. Any help would be appreciated. Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <!-- This is so viewing website is scaled well on all devices -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <!-- This is where I am getting all my icons from -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css">
        <!-- Image by fontawesome.com. Here is link to image: https://fontawesome.com/icons/info-circle?style=solid -->
        <link rel="icon" href="Images/info-circle-solid.png">
        <!-- To remove default browser styling -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/8.0.0/normalize.css">
        <!-- My style sheet -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <!-- My Sass style sheet -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/sass_style.css">
        <!-- JQuery -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- My script -->
        <script src="JavaScript/javascript.js"></script>
        <title>About</title>
    </head>
    <body>
                        <!-- Email section -->
                    <section>
                        <div class="component-div_margin component-div_width">
                            <h2 class="component-div_margin_h2_after_description">Contact</h2>
                            <p>Here is my email if you wish to contact me. Click on my email address below to copy the address to your clipboard.</p>
                            <a href="javascript:;" class="component-div_margin__email_color" id="green_email_one" onclick="CopyEmail('green_email_one')">chadwilson959@yahoo.com</a>
                        </div>
                    </section>
    </body>
    </html>
```

CSS:

```
/* Color palette courtesy of colorlovers.com. Here is the direct link to the color palette:
http://www.colourlovers.com/web/trends/websites/7853/KICKSTARTER */
/* Design inspiration courtesy of Timmy O'Mahony from his portfolio website. Here is the link to it:
http://www.colourlovers.com/web/trends/websites/7853/KICKSTARTER */

body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p {
    margin: 0;
    font-weight: normal;
}

/* .component-footer_background_color__email_border_color:
this is to add a margin to the bottom of the green email in the footer */
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,
.component-footer_background_color__email_border_color {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,a {
    color: #34302D;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 30px;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 20px;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}


/* To create spacing between borders of webpage and spacing inbetween 
seperate divs on the page */
.component-div_margin {
    margin: 5% 5% 120px 5%;
}

.component-footer_background_color__a,
#wider_screen_drop_down_menu_email,
.component-div_margin_h2_after_description,
.component-footer_background_color__a {
    color: #E6E6E6;
}

/* !important to remove previous color styling */
.component-header__left-div__nav_active_a,
.component-div_margin__email_color,
a:hover,
.wider_screen_size_header_navigation_nav a:hover {
    color: #86C543 !important;
}

/* So these animations do not repeat */
.component-drop_down_menu_open_animation,
.component-drop_down_menu_close_animation,
.component-drop_down_menu_show_animation,
.component-drop_down_menu_hide_animation,
.from_black_to_green_border_animation,
.green_email_one_border_animation {
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.from_black_to_green_border_animation,
.green_email_one_border_animation {
    animation-duration: .3s;
}

.green_email_one_border_animation {
    animation-name: green_email_one_border;
}

/* #component-description_div__h2 has this to create more spacing
in the intro */
p, #component-description_div__h2 {
    line-height: 30px;
}

/* To put anchor tags on seperate lines */
nav a:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    width: 1px;
}

/* To add seperation between links inside of navs when they are on seperate lines */
nav {
    line-height: 50px;
}

@keyframes green_email_one_border {
    from {
        color: #86C543;
        border-bottom-color: #86C543;
    }
    to {
        color: #6B9E35;
        border-bottom-color: #6B9E35;
    }
}


/* lines 335 - 418 */
/* MEDIA QUERIES */


@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    .wider_screen_size_header_navigation {
        display: block;
    }
    .open_menu_div {
        display: none;
    }
    .component-header__left-div {
        width: 50%;
    }
    .component-header__right-div {
        width: 50%;
    }
    .projects_link {
        margin-right: 0px !important;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .component-header__left-div {
        width: 25%;
    }
    .component-header__right-div {
        width: 75%;
    }    
    .projects_link {
        margin-right: 25px !important;
    }
    #wider_screen_drop_down_menu_email {
        display: inline;
        margin-right: 0px !important;
    }
    .mobile_footer_div {
        display: none;
    }
    .component-footer_background_color__div {
        width: 50%;
    }
    .wider_screen_footer_div {
        display: block;
    }
    .component-footer_background_color__h2_after_first {
        margin-bottom: 35px;
    }
    .component-footer_background_color__first_div {
        width: 60%;
    }
    .component-footer_background_color__nav {
        line-height: 30px;
    }
    .contact_header {
        margin-bottom: 40px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-height: 537px) {
    .intro_div {
        margin-bottom: 240px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
    .wider_screen_footer_div {
        display: none;
    }
    .widest_screen_footer_div {
        display: flex;
    }
    .wider_screen_footer_div_flex {
        width: 60%;
    }
    .component-footer_background_color__div {
        width: 25%;
    }
    .social_div_width {
        width: 40%;
    }
    .component-footer_background_color__first_div {
        width: 30%;
    }
    .component-div_width {
        width: 60%;
    }
}
```

JavaScript:

```
//This function is to copy the emails on each page to the clipboard and to style the link
//once it is clicked when the emails are clicked.
function CopyEmail(id) {
    var range = document.createRange();
    var selection = window.getSelection();
    SelectEmailCopying(id, range);
    RemoveAllRanges(selection);
    selection.addRange(range);
    document.execCommand('copy');
    RemoveAllRanges(selection);
}

//this function creates the range for the text of the email that is to be copied.
function SelectEmailCopying(id, range) {
    if(id === "green_email_one") {
        range.selectNodeContents(document.getElementById('green_email_one'));
    }
    else if(id === "green_email_two") {
        range.selectNodeContents(document.getElementById('green_email_two'));
    }
    else if(id === "grey_email_one") {
        range.selectNodeContents(document.getElementById('grey_email_one'));
    }
    else if(id === "grey_email_two") {
        range.selectNodeContents(document.getElementById('grey_email_two'));
    }
    else if (id === "grey_email_three") {
        range.selectNodeContents(document.getElementById('grey_email_three'));
    }
    else if(id === "drop_down_menu_email") {
        range.selectNodeContents(document.getElementById('drop_down_menu_email'));
    }
    else if(id === "wider_screen_drop_down_menu_email") {
        range.selectNodeContents(document.getElementById('wider_screen_drop_down_menu_email'));
    }
}

//This function removes all ranges once copying is done.
function RemoveAllRanges(selection) {
    selection.removeAllRanges();
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    //Gives animation to the last email link before hitting the footer on hover
    $("#green_email_one").hover(function() {
        $("#green_email_one").addClass("green_email_one_border_animation");
    }, function() {
        $("#green_email_one").removeClass("green_email_one_border_animation");
    });
});
```

And a JSFiddle link for this code:
https://jsfiddle.net/qb0d6caL/12/

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this part of code with `!important`.

```
.component-header__left-div__nav_active_a,
.component-div_margin__email_color,
a:hover,
.wider_screen_size_header_navigation_nav a:hover {
    color: red !important;//I added red as color for testing
}
```

Just remove important

Comment: Weird, I thought I needed that !important there for other parts of my code to work but apparently they work without it. But anyways, that definitely did the trick. Thanks so much!

Comment: No problem, I am glad that I can be of assistance this is my 3th successful answer :D